# How to pass simple data from controller to view in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I get an int value to the controller and I would like to send it to the according view, but i am either passing or accesing it wrong. Here is what I am trying to do:

Controller:

```
function send($int = NULL) {
    $this->set('integer', $int);

}
```

View:

```
echo $integer['int']
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

```
echo $integer['int']
```

To:

```
echo $integer;
```

The first parameter in `$this->set` is used as the variable name in your view, the second parameter is the value assigned to that variable.